# Gmail POP3 not getting all messages in Java application

Tags: java, email, gmail, jakarta-mail, pop3

I have enabled POP3 settings for my gmail. I am able to connect to the POP3 store using my password in a Java app. I have around 10k messages in my inbox.

When I call `getMessages` on the Inbox folder it returns only 280 old messages.  When I call `getMessages` in a loop, every call returns me same messages. I also tried `getMessages(start, end)` but it does not return other messages than those 280.

How do I retrieve the other messages?

Comment: Thanks **@theDmi** for your efforts

Answer (score 1):

By default, GMail's POP3 and IMAP server does not behave like standard POP3 or IMAP servers and hides messages from clients using those protocols (as well as having other non-standard behavior).

If you want to configure your GMail POP3 or IMAP settings to behave the way POP3 and IMAP are intended to behave according to their protocol specifications, you'll need to log in to your GMail account via your web browser and navigate to the `Forwarding and POP/IMAP` tab of your GMail `Settings` page and set your options to look like this:

**POP3 Download**

[X] Enable POP for **all mail** (even mail that's already been downloaded)

**IMAP Access**

[X] Enable IMAP

[X] Auto-expunge off - wait for the client to update the server

[X] Immediately delete the message forever

Comment: **@jstedfast**, I configured POP3 settings already, please have a look: [link](http://screencast.com/t/FaAVVr1r1O). Still it does not gives me all messages from my Inbox.

Comment: It sure doesn't look like you've clicked the "all mail" selection button.

Comment: **@Bill Shannon** thanks for reply, please check[POP3 Settings](http://screencast.com/t/bAgWE2LCkSnf). Still you are pointing to different settings ?

Answer (score 0):

Not a real answer, but I got around this by using Mailkit's `IMAP`. Also, this is C#, not Java code, but maybe it can help people running into the same problem:

```
      var emails = new List<EmailMessage>();

      using (var client = new ImapClient())
      {
        client.Connect("imap.gmail.com", _smtpConfig.SSLIMAPPort, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
        client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;
        client.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;
        client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
        client.Authenticate(smtpConfig.PopUsername, smtpConfig.PopPassword);

        client.Inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);
        var items = client.Inbox.Fetch(0, -1, MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure);

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
          if (item.TextBody != null)
          {
            var mime = (TextPart)client.Inbox.GetBodyPart(item.UniqueId, item.TextBody);
            var text = mime.Text;

            var email = new EmailMessage
            {
              Body = text
            };

            emails.Add(email);
          }
        }

        client.Disconnect(true);
      }

      return emails;

Thanks to jstedfast - it was all done using his docs.
```

Comment: This really is the right thing to do.  GMail's POP3 support is basically broken, since they want you to use a "download and delete" type client with it, and won't, by default, show you more messages until you "delete" the ones they've shown you.

Comment: Your other choice is a window into your last 30 days worth of email.  POP3, as a protocol, is not really designed as a "sync" protocol, and does not scale well into the thousands of messages.  Recognizing that, Gmail has nerfed it.

Comment: Thanks Max - I have been looking at this for a little bit and I didn't quite understand why it wasn't working. Hopefully this helps someone else. Mailkit's docs are great, but only once you know what you are looking for (as with any good docs).

Comment: You would be best to ask your follow up question as a new question, not as a bounty; it really doesn't relate to the original question since it's not about POP3, Java, or JavaMail.

Comment: @Max I can't cancel the bounty, so my logic is that it might as well go to someone, though you are right.