# Javamail pull messages in chunks (like pagination) GMAIL POP3

Tags: pagination, gmail, jakarta-mail, imap, pop3

Through Java app I am able to connect with GMAIL POP3 server. When I call getMessageCount() it returns me 280, though I have more than 10k mails in my Inbox. So, when I call folder.getMessages(300, 400) it gives me error because range is more than 280. For more details see my another post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31964593/2618875)

My question is:

- Is their any API to get pull emails in chunks (like as pagination)? if so can anyone give me reference to start with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a javamail limitation, this is a gmail limitation of their POP3 server.  When accessing over POP, it will only show you 300ish messages at a time until you remove them.  There is an alternate access method where you specify the login as `recent:user@gmail.com`, where instead it will show you the last 30 days worth of email.

They do this because POP3 rapidly becomes a very inefficient protocol for accessing thousands of emails, so they limit the window of messages you can see.

If you wish to access all the email, you will need to either switch to `IMAP`, or use the Gmail REST API, both of which have vastly improved mail access and experiences.

Comment: **@Max** can you please brief on 1."it will only show you 300ish messages at a time until you remove them" remove from where? means from local or from gmail server? 2."or use the Gmail REST API" can you please provide reference link ?Do you mean [GMAIL API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) this?

Comment: When the POP3 client does a LIST or UIDL, the server will only return the oldest (?) 300 messages until they are deleted from the server.  In recent mode, instead it will just show you the most recent's month worth of email, and never any more.  And yes, that is the Gmail API I mean.

Comment: If you have "leave on server" and "show all messages" set, can you see all messages?