# GMAIL POP server not marks my emails as "popped"

Tags: java, email, gmail, pop3

I am developing Java app through which I am connected to GMAIL POP server successfully. Also while fetching messages I encounter into issue reported as: [GMAIL POP ISSUE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31964593/2618875). I encounter into other GMAIL posts that explains behaviour for [GMAIL POP link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6089246?hl=en).

**EDIT:**

After following that post I am still not getting Why GMAIL server does not mark my mails as popped when I call `getMessages()`.

Due to that GMAIL is not able to return me next batch of emails.
I found that after calling getMessages(), GMAIL doesn't mark the emails as POPPED which are retrieved by `getMessages()` function.
Please let me know if any other way to retrieve GMAIL mails and also  marked them as POPPED.

Answer (score 0):

What you mean with *popped*?

If you mean mark as readed, this is incorrect. `POP` mailing system is defined to dowload in each device [*and delete from server only if requested*], so when you connect to a webmail, mail should remain unreaded for other devices can be connected to this account. If you want this behaviour you need to configure the account as `IMAP`

[Check this link](http://www.pop2imap.com/) to better understanding.

> Both POP (Post Office Protocol) and IMAP (Internet Message access protocol) allow people to get access to their email from a remote server; however, that is where most similarities end. **POP simply downloads email to your computer**, and usually (but not always) deletes the email from the remote server. **The problems arise if you have more than one device where you read your mail (desktop, laptop, tablet or phone). Here's why it's bad: You have to delete or file the same email on every device**